# Why does use statement in sub apply globally?

Tags: perl, module, scope, perl-module

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
$mech = new WWW::Mechanize;
$mech->get("http://www.google.com");
$html = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content($mech->content);
sub test
{
    use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;
}
```

The above code compiles, so the `use` statement in the `sub` is being applied globally.

Why does `perl` do this?  It doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 6):

`use Module;` has two effects.

The first is to load the module. Obviously, that has a global effect. One wouldn't want a module to be loaded multiple times if more than one other module uses it.

The second is to call the module's `import` method. For most modules, this serves to export symbols to the caller's namespace so those functions can be called without qualifying them with a full package name. This obviously affects more than just some sub since noone gives each sub its own namespace. But that's really up to you.

Some module's `import` method, however, do something quite different. They alter how code is compiled in the lexical scope in which the directive is present. These are called pragmas. `use strict;` is an example of one. It makes sense to use these modules in a sub. Using `use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;` in a sub, however, makes no sense.

Answer (score 4):

This is what [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) states:

> Because `use` takes effect at compile time, it doesn't respect the ordinary flow control of the code being compiled. In particular, putting a use inside the false branch of a conditional doesn't prevent it from being processed.

Unfortunately it doesn't give an explanation *why* it is designed that way. Possible reasons could be:

- Perl gives you lot's of freedom in many cases (TIMTOWTDI)
- `use` inside a subroutine could show your intention that you actually wanna use a module only in a specific place (even when it gets loaded globally)
- If you (re)move a particular subroutine (which contains a `use`) later, you don't have to worry about removing unused `use`'s from other places like the top of your script
- ...

Even though these ideas may sound plausible, I would avoid loading modules in subroutines because it's much clearer to have them all in one location rather than scattered all over the place?